# JSON_PRETTY_PRINT Not working as I expected

Tags: php, json

Today I'm creating a JSON in PHP. But when I want to format that then it's not format as I expected. Here is my code.

```
$data = array(
    (object)array(
        'oV' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    (object)array(
        'oV' => 'mysecondvalue',
        'oT' => 'mysecondtext',
    ),
);
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

Output:

```
[ { "oV": "myfirstvalue", "oT": "myfirsttext" }, { "oV": "mysecondvalue", "oT": "mysecondtext" } ]
```

Expected:

```
[
    {
        "oV": "myfirstvalue",
        "oT": "myfirsttext"
    },
    {
        "oV": "mysecondvalue",
        "oT": "mysecondtext"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please share what is your expected output? Looking at the code and output provided everything seems in order. So please share what you were expecting to see instead.

Comment: Sure, Here it is.

Comment: If you right click on the page in the browser and choose "View page source", it will look like you expect. Browsers just don't render all white space characters (new lines, tabs, more than two spaces etc).

Comment: Yes but I need it on website.

Comment: When asking a question, please give us _all_ information/requirements from the start. Where are you going to output this and for what purpose? To display on a web page or to use in JavaScript? For something else/more? The more context you give us, the better answer we can give you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need to cast the arrays as objects. json_encode will always encode associative arrays as objects either way.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again.

Comment: As Magnus mentioned the formatting happens correctly, however it is not displayed by the browser as-is since browsers render HTML which is whitespace insensitive. You have a variety of possible solutions such as client-side rendering libraries, however the easiest solution is probably to surround the text with a [`<pre>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).

Comment: While we were able to imply that you were asking about HTML output, that is not clearly stated in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. Pretty print uses `\n` for line breaks instead of an html element.

You can see your output like this in a rendered html page:

```
echo "<pre>" . $json . "</pre>";
```

Or, just `echo $json;` and then view source. If you're using it in a javascript block in your page you can just echo it:

```
<script>
  const json = <?php echo $json?>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks its working. But when I use this then I can't use JSON API from another server/files.

Comment: pretty print is for display only, or for readable json in a javascript function. check out my revised answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks for sharing your answer.

Comment: @MusabDeveloper - If this answer solve your issue, please accept it and let people know its been resolved. If not, please explain why not and update your question with more information.